# Should the seatpost clamp be installed backward for a carbon seatpost in an aluminum frame?

Tags: carbon, seatpost, damage, aluminum, best-practice

Is it true that the seatpost clamp must be installed backward (i.e. its slot facing the handlebars) or at least with a slight offset to avoid aligning its slot with the aluminum seat tube slot when the seatpost is made of carbon?

The reason would be that if the slots are aligned, direct pressure from the clamp slot on the tube slot would damage the seatpost.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate (see the link in the close flag). It's a decent, if somewhat niche question. I know I have heard this advice before, but it didn't become widespread practice.

Comment: Classic example of theory vs reality. In practice, unless you are gorilla with a spanner or put silly pressure on a QR and run super light seat posts, the risk of damaging the post is slim to none.  Stick to the specified torque for the seat post bolt, and the risk is 0.  If you are the gorilla with a spanner, a damaged seat post is not the only thing you need to worry about.

Comment: Don't take question-closure personally - this is a good question, so good that someone else asked it already.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie. On the contrary, it is good that it has been flagged (nice catch Weiwen Ng). I did search for a similar question before posting but since the existing question was more general, it did not show up in my search results.

Comment: While yeah, the fact that this is a duplicate can't be debated I would question the worth of linking to that specific one where there are a number of conflicting answers posted.  Makes me think that there is a element of opinion but no conclusive answer so quite valid to ask again.

Comment: @Hursey - Conflicting answers are in themselves not a bad thing and far better they sit under just one question. Voting system of SE (in theory) means the (more) correct answer will filter to the top (regardless of the one marked correct). Better for the reader to see all responses and decide for themselves. If a reader wants to turn of brain and take an answer 'as read' without thought, plenty of low quality sites (Yahoo Answers) they can go to.  This question is a very good example of no correct answer (like many, caused by difference between practice and theory).